# Using Guzzle to send multiple posts to one URL - different parameters

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to send multiple posts to Twilio using Guzzle.  My apologizes, I'm very new to guzzle.  I have seen some examples where I can set an array of URIs and run the posts in parallel.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to use the same URI with different parameters for each request.

The ONLY difference between each call would the the "TO" field.  The body, messageSID, and auth would stay the same for each parallel call.  I wanted to get this test working then eventually just be able to build the array of anywhere from 1 to 100 TO phone numbers.

Here is my code to send one request:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;    
$client = new Client(["base_uri" => "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"]);
    $options = array(
        'form_params' => [
            "Body" => "hello world",
            "To" => "+12015551234",
            "MessagingServiceSid" => "MGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
           ],
        'auth' => [
            "accountsidxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            "tokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ]

       ); 
    $response = $client->post("ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json", $options);

    echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: If you want to run the requests in parallel, make sure you have ext-curlmulti and that you call the `$client->postAsync()` function instead of the `$client->post()` function.  You will receive a promise, not a response, which can be appended to an array and passed to Promise\settle(); See "B. Async Request with Promise": https://medium.com/@ardanirohman/how-to-handle-async-request-concurrency-with-promise-in-guzzle-6-cac10d76220e